# Is it possible de-obfuscate JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

**I need your help**

Is it possible de-obfuscate this in JavaScript?

```
var_0xeda3=["\x62\x3D\x5B\x27\x30...
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fyjby68v/)

And this?

```
var bcd140526_id = '|||]|||||]||]]]]|||]|||]|]]|]]]]|||]|||]|]]|]]]]|||]|||]||]|]]]]|]|]]|||]]]]|]|||]]]]]]]|]|||]]]]]]]|||]|||||]]]]]]]|||]|||||]]|]]]]|||]|||||]]]]]]]|||]||||]|||]]]]|||]|||]||||]]]]|||]|||||]]]]]]]|||]||||]|||]]]]|||]|||||]]|]]]]|||]|||||]]]]]]]|||]||||]|||]]]]|||]|||||]]|]]]]|]|||]]|]]]]]||]]|||]]]]|||]||||]|||]]]]|||]|||]|||]]]]]|||]||||||]]]]]]|||]|||]|]|]]]]]|||]|||]||]|]]]]|||]|||]|||]]]]]|||]|||]|]]|]]]]|]|||]]|]]]]]||]]||]]]]]|||]|||]|||]]]]]|||]||||]||]]]]]|]|||]]]';
```

Comment: A simple alert("\x62\x3D\x5B\x27\x30...") will show what is inside the hexadecimal code. But, to answer your question, THIS is the real javascript, it's only obfuscated to no one understand you contents.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fyjby68v/

Comment: http://deobfuscatejavascript.com/ would be a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse engineering requires a lot of efforts. However, there's a few steps you can start with when facing obfuscating JS.

First, [deobfuscate](http://deobfuscatejavascript.com/#) and then [beautify](http://javascriptbeautifier.com/). At this point the code is still unreadable, but those steps will reduce the overall complexity.

There's one strategy that is used by most JavaScript obfuscators: they extract static values, put them in an array and substitute the static value with the array lookup.

E.g.

Note: I omitted the mangling of variable names.

```
var url = 'www.google.com';
```

Will become:

```
var allStaticValues = ['www.google.com'];
var url = allStaticValues[0];
```

That pattern is usually easy to recognize and reverse.

```
var allStaticValues = ['www.google.com'];
var obfusactedCode = 'var url = allStaticValues[0];';
var clearerCode = obfusactedCode.replace(/allStaticValues\[(.+?)\]/g, function ($0, $1) {
    return ("'" + allStaticValues[$1] + "'");
}); //var url = 'www.google.com';
```

Here's what it gives with your obfuscated code:

```
    function _fPnA(number) {
        switch (number) {
            case '||||':
                return '0';
                break;
            case '|||]':
                return '1';
                break;
            case '||]|':
                return '2';
                break;
            case '||]]':
                return '3';
                break;
            case '|]||':
                return '4';
                break;
            case '|]|]':
                return '5';
                break;
            case '|]]|':
                return '6';
                break;
            case '|]]]':
                return '7';
                break;
            case ']|||':
                return '8';
                break;
            case ']||]':
                return '9';
                break;
            default:
                return 'separate';
                break
        }
        return 'separate'
    }

    function _fKhU(code) {
        var _vTcN = window.location.hostname;
        var _vMgJ = '';
        var _vNfU = '';
        _vTcN = _vTcN.replace('http://', '');
        _vTcN = _vTcN.replace('https://', '');
        _vTcN = _vTcN.replace('www.', '');
        _vTcN = _vTcN.split('.')[0];
        for (var _vXnG = 0; _vXnG < code.length / 4; _vXnG++) {
            var _vKxS = code.substring(_vXnG * 4, (_vXnG + 1) * 4);
            if (_fPnA(_vKxS) == 'separate') {
                _vMgJ += String.fromCharCode(Number(_vNfU));
                _vNfU = ''
            } else {
                _vNfU += _fPnA(_vKxS)
            }
        }
        _vMgJ += String.fromCharCode(Number(_vNfU));
        if (_vMgJ.indexOf(_vTcN) == -1) {
            document.write('You got Post Feed widget for <em>' + _vMgJ + '</em> but you are using it for <em>' + window.location.hostname + '</em>. PLEASE REMOVE IT AND THEN <strong><a href="http://bloggercando.blogspot.com/2014/05/all-in-one-post-feed-widget-for-blogger.html" target="_blank">GET IT AGAIN</a></strong>');
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    function _fNuC(_vMgJ) {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + _vMgJ + '"></script>')
    }

    function _fLiX(pub_date, format) {
        pub_date = pub_date.split('-');
        date = new Date(pub_date[0], pub_date[1] - 1, pub_date[2].substring(0, 2));
        dd = date.getDate();
        mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
        yyyy = date.getFullYear();
        format = format.replace('dd', dd);
        format = format.replace('mm', mm);
        format = format.replace('yyyy', yyyy);
        return format
    }

    function _fJmO(content) {
        var _vUcB = '';
        var _vSiC = '<img ';
        var _vOaY = 'src="';
        var _vQlK = '"';
        index0 = content.indexOf(_vSiC);
        if (index0 != -1) {
            index1 = content.indexOf(_vOaY, index0);
            if (index0 != -1) {
                index2 = content.indexOf(_vQlK, index1 + _vOaY.length);
                if (index0 != -1) {
                    _vUcB = content.substring(index1 + _vOaY.length, index2)
                }
            }
        }
        if (_vUcB == '') {
            _vSiC = 'data-thumbnail-src="';
            _vOaY = '"';
            index0 = content.indexOf(_vSiC);
            if (index0 != -1) {
                index1 = content.indexOf(_vOaY, index0 + _vSiC.length);
                if (index0 != -1) {
                    _vUcB = content.substring(index0 + _vSiC.length, index1)
                }
            }
        }
        if (_vUcB == '') {
            _vSiC = '<iframe ';
            _vOaY = 'src="';
            _vQlK = '"';
            index0 = content.indexOf(_vSiC);
            if (index0 != -1) {
                index1 = content.indexOf(_vOaY, index0);
                if (index0 != -1) {
                    index2 = content.indexOf(_vQlK, index1 + _vOaY.length);
                    if (index0 != -1) {
                        _vUcB = content.substring(index1 + _vOaY.length, index2);
                        _vUcB = _vUcB.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '');
                        _vUcB = _vUcB.replace('http://www.youtube.com/embed/', '');
                        _vUcB = _vUcB.replace('?rel=0', '');
                        _vUcB = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + _vUcB + '/mqdefault.jpg'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _vUcB
    }

    function _fIyU(json) {
        var _vJdM = new Object();
        var _vHbI = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        _vJdM.id = json.feed.id.$t;
        key = 'blog-';
        index = _vJdM.id.indexOf(key);
        _vJdM.id = _vJdM.id.substring(index + key.length);
        _vJdM.id = _vJdM.id.replace('.comments', '');
        _vJdM.cate = new Array();
        if ('category' in json.feed) {
            for (_vXnG = 0; _vXnG < json.feed.category.length; _vXnG++) {
                _vJdM.cate[_vXnG] = json.feed.category[_vXnG].term
            }
        }
        _vJdM.title = '';
        if ('title' in json.feed) {
            _vJdM.title = json.feed.title.$t
        }
        _vJdM.subtitle = '';
        if ('subtitle' in json.feed) {
            _vJdM.subtitle = json.feed.subtitle.$t
        }
        _vJdM.admin = new Object();
        _vJdM.admin.name = 'Anonymous';
        _vJdM.admin.uri = '';
        _vJdM.admin.avatar = 'http://img1.blogblog.com/img/anon36.png';
        if ('name' in json.feed.author[0]) {
            _vJdM.admin.name = json.feed.author[0].name.$t
        }
        if ('uri' in json.feed.author[0]) {
            _vJdM.admin.uri = json.feed.author[0].uri.$t
        }
        if ('gd$image' in json.feed.author[0]) {
            if (json.feed.author[0].gd$image.src != 'http://img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif') {
                _vJdM.admin.avatar = json.feed.author[0].gd$image.src
            }
        }
        _vJdM.total_entry = Number(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t);
        _vJdM.start_index = Number(json.feed.openSearch$startIndex.$t);
        _vJdM.item_per_page = Number(json.feed.openSearch$itemsPerPage.$t);
        _vJdM.entry_number = 0;
        if ('entry' in json.feed) {
            _vJdM.entry_number = json.feed.entry.length
        }
        _vJdM.entry = new Array();
        for (_vXnG = 0; _vXnG < _vJdM.entry_number; _vXnG++) {
            _vJdM.entry[_vXnG] = new Object();
            temp = new Object();
            entry = json.feed.entry[_vXnG];
            temp.id = entry.id.$t;
            key = 'post-';
            index = temp.id.indexOf(key);
            temp.id = temp.id.substring(index + key.length);
            temp.published = '';
            if ('published' in entry) {
                temp.published = entry.published.$t
            }
            temp.cate = new Array();
            if ('category' in entry) {
                for (j = 0; j < entry.category.length; j++) {
                    temp.cate[j] = entry.category[j].term
                }
            }
            temp.title = '';
            if ('title' in entry) {
                temp.title = entry.title.$t
            }
            temp.content = '';
            if ('content' in entry) {
                temp.content = entry.content.$t
            }
            temp.summary = '';
            if ('summary' in entry) {
                temp.summary = entry.summary.$t
            }
            if (temp.summary == '') {
                temp.summary = temp.content.replace(_vHbI, '')
            }
            if (temp.content == '') {
                temp.content = temp.summary
            }
            temp.link = '';
            temp.reply_label = 'comments';
            if ('link' in entry) {
                for (j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++) {
                    if (entry.link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
                        temp.link = entry.link[j].href
                    }
                    if (entry.link[j].rel == 'replies') {
                        temp.reply_label = entry.link[j].title
                    }
                }
            }
            temp.author = new Object();
            temp.author.name = 'Anonymous';
            temp.author.uri = '';
            temp.author.avatar = 'http://img1.blogblog.com/img/anon36.png';
            a0 = entry.author[0];
            if ('name' in a0) {
                temp.author.name = a0.name.$t
            }
            if ('uri' in a0) {
                temp.author.uri = a0.uri.$t
            }
            if ('gd$image' in a0) {
                if (a0.gd$image.src != 'http://img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif') {
                    temp.author.avatar = a0.gd$image.src
                }
            }
            temp.thumbnail = '';
            if ('media$thumbnail' in entry) {
                temp.thumbnail = entry.media$thumbnail.url
            }
            temp.reply_number = 0;
            if ('thr$total' in entry) {
                temp.reply_number = Number(entry.thr$total.$t)
            }
            temp.reply_label = temp.reply_label.replace(temp.reply_number + ' ', '');
            temp.reply_to = '';
            temp.reply_json = '';
            temp.reply_title = '';
            if ('thr$in-reply-to' in entry) {
                temp.reply_to = entry['thr$in-reply-to'].href;
                temp.reply_json = entry['thr$in-reply-to'].source;
                temp.reply_json = temp.reply_json.replace('/default/', '/summary/');
                temp.reply_json = temp.reply_json + '?alt=json-in-script'
            }
            temp.pid = '';
            if ('gd$extendedProperty' in entry) {
                for (j = 0; j < entry.gd$extendedProperty.length; j++) {
                    if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[j].name == 'blogger.itemClass') {
                        temp.pid = entry.gd$extendedProperty[j].value
                    }
                }
            }
            temp.pid = temp.pid.replace('pid-', '');
            _vJdM.entry[_vXnG] = temp
        }
        return _vJdM
    }
    if (typeof(jquery_included) == 'undefined') {
        jquery_included = false
    }

    function _fQdH() {
        if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
            if (!jquery_included) {
                jquery_included = true;
                var _vZpT = document.createElement('script');
                _vZpT.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js');
                _vZpT.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_vZpT)
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                _fQdH()
            }, 50)
        } else {
            if (!($('link[href*="font-awesome.css"]').length)) {
                _vZpT = document.createElement('link');
                _vZpT.setAttribute('href', 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
                _vZpT.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_vZpT)
            }
        }
    }
    _fQdH();

    function _fIhA(str) {
        document.write(str)
    }

    function _fRcS(str) {
        if (typeof(console) != 'undefined') {
            if ('log' in console) {}
        }
    }

    function _fYtG(json) {
        if (_fKhU(bcd140526_id) == false) return;
        var _vAyB = '<div style="clear:both!important;float:none;!important;line-height:0!important"></div>';
        var _vMuA = _fIyU(json);
        var _vDyO = '';
        if (_vMuA.total_entry) {
            _vDyO += ('<div class="bcd140526_post_feed ' + bcd140526_design_style + ' ' + ((bcd140526_show_thumbnail) ? 'thumb' : 'no-thumb') + '"><ul>');
            for (var _vXnG = 0; _vXnG < _vMuA.total_entry && _vXnG < bcd140526_post_count; _vXnG++) {
                p = _vMuA.entry[_vXnG];
                _vDyO += ('<li class="item item-' + _vXnG + '">');
                _fRcS(p.thumbnail);
                if (!p.thumbnail) {
                    p.thumbnail = _fJmO(p.content)
                }
                if (bcd140526_show_thumbnail && p.thumbnail) {
                    if (bcd140526_design_style === 'column') {
                        var _vUcB = p.thumbnail;
                        if (_vUcB.indexOf('/s72-c/') != -1) {
                            _vUcB = _vUcB.replace('/s72-c/', '/s1600/')
                        } else if (_vUcB.indexOf('youtube.com') != -1) {
                            if (_vUcB.indexOf('/default.') != -1) {
                                _vUcB = _vUcB.replace('/default.', '/mqdefault.')
                            }
                        }
                        p.thumbnail = _vUcB
                    } else {
                        var _vUcB = p.thumbnail;
                        if (_vUcB.indexOf('/s72-c/') != -1) {
                            _vUcB = _vUcB.replace('/s72-c/', '/s' + bcd140526_thumbnail_size + '-c/')
                        } else if (_vUcB.indexOf('youtube.com') != -1) {
                            if (_vUcB.indexOf('/default.') != -1) {
                                _vUcB = _vUcB.replace('/default.', '/mqdefault.')
                            }
                        }
                        p.thumbnail = _vUcB
                    }
                    _vDyO += ('<a class="thumbnail" style="width:' + bcd140526_thumbnail_size + 'px;height:' + bcd140526_thumbnail_size + 'px;" href="' + p.link + '"><img src="' + p.thumbnail + '"/></a>')
                }
                _vDyO += ('<div class="item-body">');
                if (bcd140526_show_label && (typeof(p.cate[0]) != 'undefined')) {
                    _vDyO += ('<a class="cate" href="' + HOST + '/search/label/' + p.cate[0] + '">' + p.cate[0] + '</a>')
                }
                _vDyO += ('<h3 class="title"><a href="' + p.link + '">' + p.title + '</a></h3>');
                if (bcd140526_show_author_name || bcd140526_show_comment_numbers || bcd140526_show_date) {
                    _vDyO += ('<div class="meta">');
                    if (bcd140526_show_author_name) {
                        _vDyO += ('<span class="meta-item author-name"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ' + p.author.name + '</span>')
                    }
                    if (bcd140526_show_comment_numbers) {
                        _vDyO += ('<span class="meta-item comment-number"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> ' + p.reply_number + '</span>')
                    }
                    if (bcd140526_show_comment_numbers) {
                        _vDyO += ('<span class="meta-item date-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ' + _fLiX(p.published, bcd140526_date_format) + '</span>')
                    }
                    _vDyO += (_vAyB + '</div>' + _vAyB)
                }
                if (bcd140526_show_snippet) {
                    if (p.summary.length > bcd140526_snippet_length) {
                        p.summary = p.summary.substring(0, bcd140526_snippet_length) + '...'
                    }
                    if (bcd140526_show_readmore) {
                        p.summary += ' <a href="' + p.link + '#more">' + lang_readmore + '</a>'
                    }
                    _vDyO += ('<p class="snippet">' + p.summary + '</p>')
                }
                _vDyO += (_vAyB + '</div>' + _vAyB);
                _vDyO += ('</li>')
            }
            _vDyO += ('</ul>');
            if (!bcd140526_hide_copyright) {
                _vDyO += (_vAyB);
                _vDyO += ('<a target="_blank" class="copyright" href="http://bloggercando.blogspot.com/2014/05/all-in-one-post-feed-widget-for-blogger.html" style="font-size: 11px!important;text-align:right;visibility: visible;!important;text-indent:0!important;height:auto!important;width:100%!important;position:static!important;color:#999!important;display:block!important;opacity:1!important;">BloggerWidget</a>')
            }
            _vDyO += ('</div>' + _vAyB)
        } else {
            _vDyO += ('<p><em>Have no posts</em></p>')
        }
        _fIhA(_vDyO)
    }

    function _fXzN(json) {
        if (bcd140526_sort_by == 'random') {
            var _vOsU = _fIyU(json);
            rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * _vOsU.total_entry) + 1);
            if (rand + bcd140526_post_count > _vOsU.total_entry) {
                rand = _vOsU.total_entry - bcd140526_post_count + 1
            }
            if (rand < 1) {
                rand = 1
            }
            var _vXmZ = HOST + '/feeds/posts/default';
            if (bcd140526_index_label) {
                _vXmZ += '/-/' + encodeURIComponent(bcd140526_index_label)
            }
            _vXmZ += '?alt=json-in-script&max-result=' + bcd140526_post_count + '&start-index=' + rand + '&callback=_fYtG';
            _fRcS(_vXmZ);
            _fNuC(_vXmZ)
        } else {
            _fRcS('show');
            if (_fKhU(bcd140526_id)) {
                _fYtG(json)
            }
        }
    }
    var _vXmZ = HOST + '/feeds/posts/default';
    if (bcd140526_index_label) {
        _vXmZ += '/-/' + encodeURIComponent(bcd140526_index_label)
    }
    _vXmZ += '?alt=json-in-script';
    if (bcd140526_sort_by == 'random') {
        _vXmZ += '&max-results=0'
    } else {
        _vXmZ += '&max-results=' + bcd140526_post_count
    }
    _vXmZ += '&callback=_fXzN';
    _fRcS(_vXmZ);
    if (_fKhU(bcd140526_id)) {
        _fNuC(_vXmZ)
    }
```

At this point knowing in which context the code was ran and what it was initially producing would help to reverse engineering. Without an in-depth analysis, you can do a first pass over the code and unmangle variable names that you can.

For instance we may change `var _vTcN = window.location.hostname;` to `var hostName = window.location.hostname;` and rename `_vTcN` to `hostName` where it makes sense.

After a few passes when you feel the code is more readable then you can find the execution entry point and work it out from there.